# Generic list custom paging

Tags: jquery, pagination

I am using jquery ajax method in my app and from the web method I am returning a huge generic list.Upon jquery ajax success I am rendering div's with the data retruned from the web method.
B'coz the data returned is very huge,I need to paginate the results.Initially I am returning the first 10 records using **List.Take(10)**.Then upon the next pages button clicks I do not understand how to return the next records.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Skip method to skip records to the appropriate page. For example:

```
List.Skip(n).Take(10)
```

You'll probably need some bounds checking for the size of the list but that's not very difficult.

Comment: Thanks David,I am able to get the next records with List.Skip(n).Take(10). Basically I have a div with buttons for page numbers and upon clicking on any of the buttons I want to make a async request to the server and get the results.so upon clicking on any of these page numbers I want to invoke the same Jquery ajax method,passing name of the button clicked.Is that possible?

Comment: It's possible, I would recommend studying the following Phil Hack blog post as well as the sample projects he makes available.
http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why returning huge data and paginate whith js. Its better for performance to get only the data that you have in your grid.

For page1 display 1-10
For page2 display 11-20  etc

The request must contain the page number so SQL the limit you want for each grid page